# WSL2 - Docker without Docker Desktop - cloud_sql_proxy does not work with VPN

Tags: windows, docker, vpn, wsl-2

So far I have worked/developed with Windows 10, Docker Desktop and WSL2. Now I had to remove Docker Desktop for licensing reasons and decided to run Docker natively in my WSL2 distro. This also works flawlessly. I can access my Docker applications in WSL from Windows.

For the data connections I use the [cloud_sql_proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy#docker) from Google.
Again, no problems here. However, they occur as soon as I turn on the VPN. Then I can't connect to the database anymore. Everything else works!
The following:

1. VPN turned off. Connect to the DB via the cloud_sql container. Everything Okay
2. turn on VPN. DB connection remains established, but breaks down as soon as a reconnect is necessary.
3. VPN switched on. LOG in container: `net/http: TLS handshake timeout`

Using

- gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.31.2
- Windows 10
- Ubuntu-20.04
- VPN L2TP (Windows nativ)

Using the cloud_sql_proxy service instead of the Docker container works. Can anyone help me with this? Why does it not work with the Docker container?